# Xlsxwriter Excel Chart Border

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is there a way to remove an Excel chart border using Xlsxwriter? I need my chart to blend in to an Excel sheet without the grid lines showing and I haven't had any luck so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`set_chartarea()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-set-chartarea) method to set the border for the chart object:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('chart.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write_column('A1', [3, 6, 9, 12, 9])

chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart.add_series({'values': '=Sheet1!$A$1:$A$5'})

# Turn off the chart border.
chart.set_chartarea({'border': {'none': True}})

worksheet.insert_chart('C2', chart, {'x_offset': 25, 'y_offset': 10})

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Perfect! Works like a gem. Thanks for the help.